# WPF DependencyProperty: how to specify the OPPOSITE action of PropertyChangedCallback?

Tags: wpf, callback, 2-way-object-databinding, dependencyobject

I'm adding a custom string DependencyProperty to a WPF UserControl that will be bound to a string property in my business object that contains rtf.

My `PropertyChangedCallback` works: it contains a snippet of code to use the `e.NewValue` rtf string to programmatically do a `range.Load()` on the RichTextBox nested in my UserControl, feeding it the rtf, when the DataContext changes or the business object's rtf string property changes (via `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

**But what, or where, is the opposite callback** to go back the other direction? When the inner RichTextBox loses focus after the user types/pastes their rich text, I need to run a mirror-image snippet of code to do the `range.Save()` to an rtf string, and that string needs to be written to the string property of the business object at that moment.

I am coming from Winforms, so I'm looking for the WPF analog of the Format/Parse pair that I'm accustomed to for round-tripping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 this.SetCurrentValue(MyDependencyProperty, range.Save());
```

`this` being the UserControl that owns the DP.

Also make sure your binding `Mode=TwoWay`.

Comment: Man, so many hours of Googling and blind trial and error, just to find out it's a one-liner :)